# preg_match fails with simple pattern

Tags: preg-match

I'm trying to analyze the content of an **uploaded file** (which is supposed to be an image), in order to stop any malicious tampering. So, before processing, I want to detect if the file contains PHP code for instance.

```
$patern = "/<?php/" ;
                    $handle  = fopen ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "r");
                    if ($handle) 
                    {
                        while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false)
                        {                                   
                                if ( preg_match ( $patern , $buffer ) );
                                {
                                echo "PHP files are forbidden";                                 
                                }                               
                        }
                        if (!feof($handle))
                            {
                            echo "Error: fgets() failed\n";
                            }
                        fclose($handle);
                    }
```

After sending an image, the result is "PHP files are forbidden" echoed a 180 times.
Ok normal, it's in the loop, but there is not a single **php** pattern in mi pic ... 
What's the problem ? The patern ? preg_match ? The handel ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,

The mistake is :  syntax error : semicolon at the end of :

```
 if ( preg_match ( $patern , $buffer ) );
```

Otherwise it works fine